# Json Response is undefined

Tags: javascript, json, jquery

This is driving me nuts, I have been through every article I have seen on Google and here and two days later, 101 variants later I am still no further forward.

The success 201 works perfectly, I get an alert with bound items.  The 404 doesn't work at all, no matter what I try the ErrorDesc is always undefined.  I have got it working that it can hit this 404 function with a fixed string, but I want the user to know why there is an error.

I have used fiddler to look at the request and response.  It looks fine, both the request and response are well formed JSON:

Raw Request:

```
{"Bedrooms":"3","BuildingsAD":"Yes","BuildingsMD":"No","BulidingSI":"100000","ContentsAD":"No","ContentsMD":"No","ContentsPOL":"No","ContentsSI":"5000","EffectiveDate":"03/10/2012 23:40:10","EL":"N","MD":"No","NCD":"1","POL":"No","PropType":"Terraced","RiskPostcode":"SW19 1TS","SchemeRef":"20","TA":"No","TenantTheft":"No","TenantType":"Professional","Theft":"No","TransactionDate":"03/10/2012 23:40:10","VolExcess":"250","YearBuilt":"2000 +","ErrorDesc":"123"}

Raw Response:

{"RatingId":"f5733e9d-bc9d-4026-8d5f-ce4f750a3a42","SchemeRef":"20","EffectiveDate":"03/10/2012 23:40:10","TransactionDate":"03/10/2012 23:40:10","Bedrooms":"3","BuildingsAD":"Yes","BuildingsMD":"No","BulidingSI":"100000","ContentsAD":"No","ContentsMD":"No","ContentsPOL":"No","ContentsSI":"5000","EL":"N","MD":"No","NCD":"1","POL":"No","PropType":"Terraced","RiskPostcode":"SW19 1TS","TA":"No","TenantTheft":"No","TenantType":"Professional","Theft":"No","VolExcess":"250","YearBuilt":"2000 +","Error":true,"ErrorDesc":"Rating Sheet not found"}


    <script type="text/javascript">

        function CalcRating() {
            //create a Json object based on data entered by user
            var RatingItems = {
                AD: $("#AD").val(),
                AdminFee: $("#AdminFee").val(),
                Bedrooms: $("#Bedrooms").val(),
                BuildingsAD: $("#BuildingsAD").val(),
                BuildingsMD: $("#BuildingsMD").val(),
                BuildingsPremium: $("#BuildingsPremium").val(),
                BulidingSI: $("#BulidingSI").val(),
                ContentsAD: $("#ContentsAD").val(),
                ContentsMD: $("#ContentsMD").val(),
                ContentsPOL: $("#ContentsPOL").val(),
                ContentsPremium: $("#ContentsPremium").val(),
                ContentsSI: $("#ContentsSI").val(),
                EffectiveDate: $("#EffectiveDate").val(),
                EL: $("#EL").val(),
                IPT: $("#IPT").val(),
                MD: $("#MD").val(),
                NCD: $("#NCD").val(),
                POL: $("#POL").val(),
                PropType: $("#PropType").val(),
                RatingId: $("#RatingId").val(),
                RiskPostcode: $("#RiskPostcode").val(),
                SchemeRef: $("#SchemeRef").val(),
                TA: $("#TA").val(),
                TenantTheft: $("#TenantTheft").val(),
                TenantType: $("#TenantType").val(),
                Theft: $("#Theft").val(),
                TransactionDate: $("#TransactionDate").val(),
                TotalPremium: $("#TotalPremium").val(),
                VolExcess: $("#VolExcess").val(),
                YearBuilt: $("#YearBuilt").val(),
                ErrorDesc: "123"
            };
            //call jQuery Ajax method which calls Json.stringify method to convert
            //the Json object into string and send it with post method
            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/qsletpropertyom",
                data: JSON.stringify(RatingItems),
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                statusCode: {
                    201: function (result) {
                        alert("Total Premium: " + result.TotalPremium + ", Total Buildings Premium " + result.BuildingsPremium + ", Total Contents Cover " + result.ContentsPremium + ", Admin Fee " + result.AdminFee);
                    },
                    404: function (result1) {

                        alert(result.ErrorDesc);

                    },
                    500: function (result2) {
                        alert("Unknown Error");
                    }

                }
            });
        }
```

Please let me know the error of my ways!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're using `result.ErrorDesc` when you were probably expecting `result1.ErrorDesc` - but that's just a typo I guess.

Second of all, if I get you right, you want to display error description to the user when ajax hits 404 (page not found)? If so, most likely you won't be able to do that since there is no data passed to your 404 handler.

Perhaps you're looking for something else like `error` option for ajax (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

From jQuery documentation: `error` "A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests."

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/api/qsletpropertyom",
    data: JSON.stringify(RatingItems),
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        // textStatus will contain "Not Found" for 404 errors
    }
});
```

EDIT:
Apparently, the 404 handler used in `statusCode` map definition (as you did) gets 3 arguments, just as `error` option does. Here's working example: http://jsfiddle.net/QsHdV/2/

Note that first argument you get there is jquery XHR object not some result data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is that you are expecting to get the response text as the first argument in the 404 case, which is not what jQuery returns.

Here some info taken from the [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/%20jQuery%20docs) :

> **statusCode(added 1.5)Map**
>
> If the request is successful, the status code functions take the same parameters as the success callback; **if it results in an error, they take the same parameters as the error callback**.
>
> **error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) Function**
>
> A function to be called if the request fails. The function receives three arguments: The jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object, a string describing the type of error that occurred and an optional exception object, if one occurred. Possible values for the second argument (besides null) are "timeout", "error", "abort", and "parsererror". When an HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the textual portion of the HTTP status, such as "Not Found" or "Internal Server Error." As of jQuery 1.5, the error setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. Note: This handler is not called for cross-domain script and JSONP requests. This is an Ajax Event.
>
> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)Function, Array**
>
> A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object. As of jQuery 1.5, the success setting can accept an array of functions. Each function will be called in turn. This is an Ajax Event.

As you can see, you aren't given a response data object as an argument when an HTTP error occurs.

Comment: Thanks Both, looks like my approach is totally wrong.  The 404 is actually generated by me when an agents number is not found.  It could be a 500 or anything.  I wanted to give the user something helpful rather than a generic 'it didn't work'.  I can approach this by sending a 500 but then logging something in the database to be helpful. I guess I could update the sending model and do a 200 with a different message too but that puts logic in the page which I would prefer to avoid.  Wish I could have worked this out earlier guys, amny thanks for your feedback.

Comment: I now have this working.  I updated the controller code to return a 202 instead of 201 with an updated data item which represents the custom error message.  This is probably not a text book approach but works perfectly for what I need.

Comment: It seems like you should just use a proper 404 and then give the user a clean message telling them what went wrong. If you are requesting a number and receive a 404, then tell the user that the number wasn't found.

Comment: jn, this isn't viable with potentially several hundred errors.  I didn't want to provide a generic error.